# Router page of vue.js is unable to show double brace content

Tags: vue.js, variables, vue-component, vue-router

I have this router page "flash.vue.js" with these codes -

```
var Flash = { template: `

<div align="center" id="width-box">
<span>Hello {{ message }}!</span>
</div>

    `};
```

In the index file I have -

```
<script src="vue.js"></script>
<script src="vue-router.js"></script>

{{ message }}

<router-link to="/flash">Flash</router-link>
<router-link to="/express">Express</router-link>
<router-view></router-view>
<script>
var routes = [ { path: '/', component: Home }, { path: '/express', component: Express },
{ path: '/flash', component: Flash} ];
  
var router = new VueRouter({ routes: routes, mode: 'history', base: '/' });
  
 var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router: router,
     data: {message: 'Hello Cat!'}
  })
</script>
```

Index Page is successfully showing "Hello Cat" through `{{ message }}`,
But "***flash.vue.js***" is not showing anything with `{{ message }}`. What is the problem? How to fix it? Please help! Thanks.

Comment: Missing a `<router-view>`,  `Home` and `Express` components, and the `Flash` component has no data or `message` property, only a template.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Flash component has no data but it is present inside the index where it is called.

Comment: It won't be automatically passed from the App root component to a route view component.  In other parent/child situations you would use props for that, but not usually from a parent to a *dynamic* child.  It's probably intended to be global data, you could use Vuex for that.